# If we have proved that $n$ cannot be greater than $9$, have we also proved that the most it can be is $9$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

If we have proved that $n$ cannot be greater than $9$, have we also proved that the most it can be is $9$? I am conflicted because it could still be impossible for $n$ to be greater than, say, $5$, and it could never actually be $9$, but because we haven't proved this tighter bound, it seems it is valid to conclude that the possibility exists for $n$ to be $9$, as "can" expresses mere possibility. Which of these viewpoints is correct?

Edit: if we have shown $n \le 9$, is this logically equivalent to saying the most $n$ can be is $9$, or is that concluding too much; we don't know if it actually is possible for $n$ to be $9$?

Comment: Without more information, the only thing you can deduce from $n \le 9$ is ... $n \le 9$.

Comment: @nicomezi Welcome to the tautology club ;)

Comment: @nicomezi From $n\le 9$ I can conclude that $n<12$. If that is needed in context. But it is clearly weaker.

Comment: It is implicit (but clear IMO) that I meant a stronger deduction. But strictly speaking you are right. @JeppeStigNielsen

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Also strictly speaking $n \not> 9$ is not equivalent to $n\leq 9$. Unless you assume that we are dealing with a total order.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, Correct, I am implicitly assuming that we are dealing with the total order on $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ or something. If $12$ was meant as the set $\{ 0, 1, 2, \ldots, 11\}$, and $n$ was a set too, and $\le$ was meant to mean $\subseteq$, then I would be wrong, two sets could overlap without one being included in the other. But all this is hardly helpful for the question asked(?).

Comment: This is what I could have asked in return to your first comment. :) @JeppeStigNielsen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ cannot exceed $9,$ then $n$ is indeed at most $9$ (in fact, these two claims are equivalent), which is not to say that it is not also at most $7$ nor a suggestion that $n$ in the context ever attains the value $9.$

"Every $n$ is at most $7$" is a stronger assertion that "every $n$ is at most $9$", and the two assertions *are* consistent with each other: they can—but needn’t—both be true.

Orthogonal point:

> if we have shown that $n \le 9$, is this logically equivalent to saying that the most $n$ can be is $9$

Technically they are mathematically equivalent but not logically equivalent, because if we change the meaning of that inequality sign they may no longer have the same meaning.

Answer (score 2):

To my ears, $n$ cannot be greater than $9$ is $n\not> 9$, and $n$ can at most be $9$ is $n\le 9$, and the two are equivalent. So I would say yes.

Both wordings leave open the possibility that $n$ is precisely $9$, but we do not know if equality holds.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\boxed{n \text{ cannot be greater than } 9}
&\Longleftrightarrow n\notin (9, +\infty) \\
&\Longleftrightarrow n\in(\mathbb{R}/(9, +\infty)) \\
&\Longleftrightarrow n\in(-\infty, 9] \\
&\Longleftrightarrow \boxed{n \text{ is at most 9 }}
\end{align}$$